# Related to Android app thumbnail issue

Tags: android, tabs, grid

I am making an app with a grid view to display thumbnails of images stored in my drawable folder of project.

But it doesn't shows any thumbnails when i run the app on emulator.

The screen appears for 1 sec(blank) and then closes saying "**Unfortunately Home has stopped**". What to do?"

Home.java

```
public class Home extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(Home.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    });

}
```

}

ImageAdapter.java

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView1(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    return imageView;
}

// references to our images
private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.images, R.drawable.home,
        R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.sync,
        R.drawable.images, R.drawable.home,
        R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.sync

};

@Override
public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
}
```

the detailed logcat :

08-13 01:45:12.189: D/dalvikvm(818): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 39K, 6% free 2702K/2860K, paused 142ms, total 326ms
08-13 01:45:12.290: I/dalvikvm-heap(818): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.358MB for 635812-byte allocation
08-13 01:45:12.699: D/dalvikvm(818): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3K, 5% free 3319K/3484K, paused 410ms, total 410ms
08-13 01:45:13.591: D/AndroidRuntime(818): Shutting down VM
08-13 01:45:13.699: W/dalvikvm(818): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x414c4700)
08-13 01:45:13.959: E/AndroidRuntime(818): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-13 01:45:13.959: E/AndroidRuntime(818): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-13 01:45:13.959: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2179)
08-13 01:45:13.959: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.widget.GridView.onMeasure(GridView.java:1040)
08-13 01:45:13.959: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
08-13 01:45:13.959: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5008)
08-13 01:45:13.959: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
08-13 01:45:13.959: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1052)
08-13 01:45:13.959: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:590)
08-13 01:45:13.959: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
08-13 01:45:13.959: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5008)
08-13 01:45:13.959: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
08-13 01:45:13.959: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
08-13 01:45:13.959: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:728)
08-13 01:45:13.959: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:477)
08-13 01:45:13.959: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
08-13 01:45:13.959: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5008)
08-13 01:45:13.959: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
08-13 01:45:13.959: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
08-13 01:45:13.959: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:728)
08-13 01:45:13.959: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:477)
08-13 01:45:13.959: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
08-13 01:45:13.959: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5008)
08-13 01:45:13.959: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
08-13 01:45:13.959: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
08-13 01:45:13.959: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5008)
08-13 01:45:13.959: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:302)
08-13 01:45:13.959: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
08-13 01:45:13.959: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5008)
08-13 01:45:13.959: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
08-13 01:45:13.959: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2189)
08-13 01:45:13.959: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
08-13 01:45:13.959: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1905)
08-13 01:45:13.959: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1104)
08-13 01:45:13.959: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1284)
08-13 01:45:13.959: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
08-13 01:45:13.959: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
08-13 01:45:13.959: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
08-13 01:45:13.959: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
08-13 01:45:13.959: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
08-13 01:45:13.959: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
08-13 01:45:13.959: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
08-13 01:45:13.959: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-13 01:45:13.959: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-13 01:45:13.959: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
08-13 01:45:13.959: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-13 01:45:13.959: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
08-13 01:45:13.959: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
08-13 01:45:13.959: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-13 01:45:13.959: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: The detailed logcat at the time of stopping:

Comment: Yes. that would help us to know where the error occurs

Comment: 08-13 01:45:13.959: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at 
08-13 01:45:13.959: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-13 01:45:13.959: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Edit your question and paste the logcat there itself